# Photoshop/Illustrator CS6 autotrace including border

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, fill, live-trace

Autotrace is tracing including the bounding line in its trace.  I take the trace, paste it back into photoshop using paste paths. When I do a fill, it is filling the outsides of my art, not inside the lines.  So, basically, I end up with a black rectangle since the original lines are still there.

This causes other problems.  In photoshop, select a black ring, then cut and paste it into Illustrator.  Essentially you have a transparent background.    When trace gets to close to the top, it starts tracing back along the border instead of closing the ring.  So all four of the sides have a flat spot in addition to the above problem.  I got by the flat sides by importing images with a white background making that border be away from my lines a little.  Still it was a pain for a newbe.

So, Is there a setting or something that I am missing?

Comment: I posted this somewhere else.  Apparently, it is a CS6 bug.  Very irritating.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the encompassing rectangle in Illustrator before copying anything using the Direct Selection Tool (white arrow)... or am I missing something??

Often it's helpful to select and remove hollow paths as well (those without fill and strokes applied).

Trace is a trace, that doesn't necessarily mean art is complete and ready to use as traced. It often takes a little manual refinement to the traced artwork.

Answer (score -1):

I posted this somewhere else.  Apparently this is a CS6 bug.

Comment: Could you add a link to where you posted it?